# C# Launch application with multiple arguments

Tags: c#, process

I have been trying to start an application from a C# application but it fails to start properly. From the cmd the application plus the arguments launch a small window showing the output then the application in minimized to the system tray.

Launching the application from the C# application using the code below results in the process appearing in the task manager but nothing else, no output window, no system tray icon. What could be the issue?

```
    myProcess.StartInfo.FileName = ...;
    myProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = ...;
    myProcess.Start();
```

also tried passing the following

```
    myProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true; //tried both
    myProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false; //tried both 
    myProcess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
```

using

```
    Process.Start(Filename, args)
```

also did not work. Would really appreciate any help on how to tackle this.

UPDATE:
I think the issue maybe the multiple arguments that are to be passed to the process

```
RunMode=Server;CompanyDataBase=dbname;UserName=user;PassWord=passwd;DbUserName=dbu;Server=localhost;LanguageCode=9
```

regards

Comment: Try enclosing the arguments in single quotes.

Answer (score 14):

I don't see any mistake in your code. I have written a little program that prints out its args to the console

```
static void Main (string[] args)
{
     foreach (string s in args)
         Console.WriteLine(s);
     Console.Read(); // Just to see the output
}
```

and then I have put it in C:, being the name of the app "PrintingArgs.exe", so I have written another one that executes the first:

```
Process p = new Process();
p.StartInfo.FileName = "C:\\PrintingArgs.exe";
p.StartInfo.Arguments = "1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18";
p.Start();
```

this gives me the desired output of the list of numbers. The app that calls PrintingArgs exits as it reachs p.Start(), this could be avoided by using `p.WaitForExit();` or just `Console.Read();`.
Also I have used both `UseShellExecute` and `CreateNoWindow`. Only in the case that

```
p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
```

makes the PrintingArgs app not to show a window (even if I put only `p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true` it shows a window).

Now it comes to my mind that maybe your are passing the args in a wrong way and makes the other program to fail and close inmediately, or maybe you are not pointing to the right file. Check paths and names, in order to find any mistake you could omit.
Also, using

```
 Process.Start(fileName, args);
```

does not uses the info you set up with StartInfo into your Process instance.

Hope this will help,
regards

Comment: Another reminder, for anyone using Process like this, don't forget that they need to be disposed. So, it's better to put them in a using clause.
For example:
`using (Process p = new Process())`
`{`
`    //do stuff`
`}`

Answer (score 6):

Not sure if anyone is still following this but here is what I came up with.

```
string genArgs = arg1 + " " + arg2;
string pathToFile = "Your\Path";
Process runProg = new Process();
try
{
    runProg.StartInfo.FileName = pathToFile;
    runProg.StartInfo.Arguments = genArgs;
    runProg.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
    runProg.Start();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Could not start program " + ex);
}
```

Adding a space in the string allowed two arguments to be passed into the program I wanted to run. The program ran without issue after executing the code.

Answer (score 2):

Have u set your ProcessWindowStyle to Hidden?
This is my code, working fine:

```
Process p=new Process();
p.StartInfo.FileName = filePath;//filePath of the application
p.StartInfo.Arguments = launchArguments;
p.StartInfo.WindowStyle = (ProcessWindowStyle)ProcessStyle;//Set it to **Normal**
p.Start();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
      System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(FileName,args);
```

Eg

```
     System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("iexplore.exe",Application.StartupPath+ "\\Test.xml");
```