# Adding commands to shortcut / exe file

Tags: c#

Is it possible to add commands in shortcut or exe file it self? As i seen on this page, for Steam.exe you can add any command to run your file with some ways else than normal, here is image for something like this:

http://puu.sh/2Ta1K.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to use arguments to lunch aplication or create shortcut with target with arguments.

[C# Launch application with multiple arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3456228/c-sharp-launch-application-with-multiple-arguments)

Steam.exe also there is also use Target to set parameters.  below is the part of documentation from Steam.exe site.

[**Setting Steam Launch Options**](https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=5623-QOSV-5250)

*Navigate to your Steam installation (by default this is located at C:\Program Files\Steam)
Right-click on Steam.exe (this file is listed as an application and features the black and white Steam logo) and select Create Shortcut
Right-click on the new shortcut and go to Properties
Select the Shortcut tab
In the Target: field add the launch options which you would like to use after the Steam.exe location (make sure to separate all launch options with a space - For example, " -launchoption1 -launchoption2")
Click Apply and then OK to close the Properties window*

Answer (score 0):

Every executable is ran with `arguments` (those are not commands but arguments rather). The executable then needs to handle those `arguments`, so even if you include some dummy `arguments` they won't affect the executable in any way.