# Access other program config file using another program C#

Tags: c#, configuration, configuration-files

I have a program A which is console application.
Then I have program B which is C# windows application.
With in program B I want to give facility to users to view and edit the config file of A.

How can I access the config file of A ; when I'm using application B.
Is that possible?

Comment: In application B when you are reading and writing the config file?

Comment: In App B I have button to 'View config in A'. In there I want to open the config in A and edit.

Comment: you just need to start Application A from B and pass location of file through arguments. check this: link:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3456228/c-sharp-launch-application-with-multiple-arguments

Comment: Check out the answer in the post - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6341906/read-custom-configuration-file-in-c-sharp-framework-4-0. This should help you get going